# R frequency count by matching strings

Tags: r

Please can someone help me with this question? Thanks a lot!

I have some data like this:

```
    A             B
fruit     red apple
fruit   green apple
fruit  yellow apple
fruit          kiwi
fruit   golden kiwi
juice   apple juice
juice  orange juice
```

and I want to get the following:

```
    A             B         freq
fruit         apple            3
fruit          kiwi            2
juice         apple            1
juice        orange            1
```

I can provide a vector of strings to search for in B (i.e. I know I want to look for "apple", "kiwi", and "orange"). If for example there is a "banana" in "fruit" and I don't have "banana" in the list of items I want to search for, simply display "banana" in the result with freq 1.

Comment: Try `sum(grepl('apple',data[,2]))`  to get the number of rows with "apple" .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, thanks! But what I really want is the frequency of "apple" within each category in A, i.e. the frequency of 'apple" in "fruit" and "juice".

Comment: Ok, then think :-) `sum(grepl('apple',data[data[,1]=="fruit",2]))` and so on.

Comment: You're right, this sure works! But the problem is, my data set is very large, and I have many more categories (thousands) in A than the given two. Is there a more automatic way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Counting the number of observations with a particular value is a one-liner with `table`:

```
library(stringr)
table(paste(df$A, str_extract(df$B, paste(lookingfor, collapse="|")), sep="."))
#  fruit.apple   fruit.kiwi  juice.apple juice.orange 
#            3            2            1            1
```

Here, `paste(lookingfor, collapse="|")` generates a regex looking for all your words, `str_extract` extracts the words you're looking for, the outer `paste` groups together the `A` variable with the extracted value (separating with a `.`) and `table` computes the counts for each pairing.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion out and it works great! Just one last thing: how can I modify your code so that I don't get outputs like `fruit.NA`? This happens when `B` contains items other than those in `lookingfor`. I'd like to have meaningful outputs (e.g. `fruit.banana`) in this case.

Comment: @scat5218 it would be easy to filter to remove any observation with no matches in B; you'd want something like `e <- str_extract(df$B, paste(lookingfor, collapse="|"))` and `table(paste(df$A[!is.na(e)], e[!is.na(e)], sep="."))`. If you want to extract "banana" from column B you'll have to add it to `lookingfor`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dataframe is named `df`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(categ = sapply(regmatches(B, regexec("apple|kiwi|orange",B)),'[',1)) %>%
  group_by(A,categ) %>%
  mutate(freq = n()) %>%
  select(A,B=categ,freq) %>%
  summarize(freq = first(freq))
```

returns

```
      A      B freq
1 fruit  apple    3
2 fruit   kiwi    2
3 juice  apple    1
4 juice orange    1
```

Comment: Thank you George! Do you know why this one gives me a `Error in regexec("apple|kiwi|orange", c(6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L)) : 
  invalid 'text' argument`?

Comment: if you try ?regexec, you will see that the second argument must be a character vector (where matches are sought). I have passed the name of the 2nd column of your dataframe to the text argument.

Comment: I see! One last question: is there a way to display in results items in `B` that are not included in my search list? There are many types of items in my actual `B` column. The items I specify to search for are the major ones, but I do want to know what the other ones are. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick for you.  It relies on the fact that the vector of strings you provide match exactly with the words in your original data.

```
# your data
df <- data.frame(A = rep(c("fruit", "juice"), c(5, 2)),
    B = c("red apple", "green apple", "yellow apple", "kiwi", "golden kiwi", "apple juice", "orange juice"))

# vector of strings to search for
lookingfor <- c("apple", "kiwi", "orange", "banana")

# function to split up words in df$B and find those that match to those in looking for
found <- function(longname, shortnames) {
    splitlong <- strsplit(longname, " ")[[1]]
    index <- match(splitlong, shortnames)
    res <- if(all(is.na(index))) NA else shortnames[index[!is.na(index)][1]]
    res
    }

# apply the function to your data
df$C <- sapply(df$B, found, shortnames=lookingfor)

# summarize
aggregate(data.frame(freq=!is.na(df$C)), list(A=df$A, B=df$C), sum)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it in R but it complains for `Error in strsplit(longname, " ") : non-character argument`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach.  First find out how many "categories" there are in the first column.

```
categs <- unique(data[,1])
fruits <- c('apple','orange', 'kiwi') # or whatever
results<-matrix(ncol=3)
```

Then for each value in `categs`, search for each type of known fruit.

```
for (j in 1:length(categs) ) {
    for (k in 1:length(fruits) ) {
        results[1 + j*(k-1),1]<-categs[j]
        results[1 + j*(k-1),2]<-fruits[j]
        results[1 + j*(k-1),1]<-sum(grepl(fruits[k],data[data[,1]==fruits[k],2]))
        }
    }
```

I haven't tested that so no doubt I got some indexing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By taking the data set that you have and declaring it `dat`, you can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%

  mutate(B = sub(' juice', '', B),
         B = ifelse(grepl(' apple', B), 'apple', B),
         B = ifelse(grepl('golden ', B), sub('golden ', '', B), B)) %>%

group_by(A, B) %>%
summarise(count = n())
```

Other rules would have to be added to the mutate statement.