# R: Count frequency of string (inside parentheses) in a dataframe column using regexp

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe

The column `funders` of dataframe `research` lists names of funders in parentheses, like this:

```
Funder 1 (FWF)
Another Funding Organization (FWF)
Funder 2 (ERC) supported this research.
Yet another one (Leverhulme Trust), and another (ERC). They helped us!
We thank this funder (FWF) for their support
```

I want to extract all the funder names within parentheses and rank them based on their frequency counts.

I could not do it with this code:

```
df <- data.frame(table(research$funders))
funder <- "(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))"
sapply(df, function(x) {
  sapply(funder, function(y) {
    sum(grepl(y, x, perl=TRUE))
  })
})
```

The code shows this unwelcome result:

```
Var1.(?<=\\().*?(?=\\)) Freq.(?<=\\().*?(?=\\)) 
                     97                       0
```

But I instead would like to have:

```
FWF                  3
ERC                  2
Leverhulme Trust     1
```

How can I do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew, I had seen it, but it didn't help: All the solutions there simply counted the number of occurrences of parentheses, rather than counting the frequeny of each distinct value within the parentheses.

Comment: This one [does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638742/r-frequency-count-by-matching-strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract everything inside round brackets using `regmatches` and `gregexpr`. Then use `table` to count it's frequencies.

```
table(unlist(regmatches(string, gregexpr('\\(.*?\\)', string))))

#             (ERC)              (FWF) (Leverhulme Trust) 
#                 2                  3                  1
```

Same thing can be done using `stringr::str_extract_all` :

```
table(unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(string, '\\(.*?\\)')))
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked; and to sort by frequency count I used `sort(table..., decreasing=TRUE)`.